# iOS 9 : Get Value From NSURLSessionDataTask In Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios9

I had iOS framework which it send `JSON` to server using `NSURLSessionDataTask` like this :

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    int responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];

    if (responseStatusCode == 200)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.delegate onJsonHttpResult:data andStatusResponse:responseStatusCode];
});
    }
    else
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.delegate onJsonHttpResult:nil andStatusResponse:responseStatusCode];
});
    }

}];

[postDataTask resume];
```

but whenever I run it, `[self.delegate onJsonHttpResult:nil andStatusResponse:responseStatusCode];` not called.

is there any way to get value outside `NSURLSessionDataTask` when it run inside the framework ?

Thanks

Comment: Is method onjsonhttprekult is the custom protocol? If so, Do you have conform this protocol?

Comment: Hi KGen, yeah it custom protocol. I tried put onJsonHttpResult outside NSURLSessionDataTask, it work but I don't understand when I put inside NSURLSessionDataTask

Comment: Can you show the protocol designed and controller in which you are using. Did you assign the protocol for the controller like controllerObj.delegate = self; etc

Comment: whats the value you getting of `responseStatusCode`?

Comment: Hi Piyush Patel, responseStatusCode value like 200 or 404

Comment: Did you tried after put that code right after the responseStatusCode without if...else... condition?

Comment: Try with `if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(onJsonHttpResult:andStatusResponse:)]) {
        [self.delegate onJsonHttpResult:data andStatusResponse:responseStatusCode];
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help but I still need delegate to return my value outside framework.

I got issued that whenever I done with NSURLSessionDataTask, delegate is became null, I think it cause that delegate already released after I got response from NSURLSessionDataTask, So I tried to change @property delegate to strong and it work. I can return my value using delegate again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create and use `APIHelperClass` with completionBlock.
That will be more easy and affective then use of custom `Delegate` as per my view.

To create it you can do as follow:

In `APIHelperClass.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface APIHelperClass : NSObject

+(void)apiCallSharedSessionPOST:(NSURLRequest *)request  withCompletionHandlar:(void (^) (NSDictionary *dicResult,NSError *error, int status))completionBlock;


@end
```

And

`APIHelperClass.m`

```
#import "APIHelperClass.h"

@implementation APIHelperClass


+(void)apiCallSharedSessionPOST:(NSURLRequest *)request  withCompletionHandlar:(void (^) (NSDictionary *dicResult,NSError *error, int status))completionBlock;

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

        NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:
                                      ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                          NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
                                          int responseStatusCode = (int)[httpResponse statusCode];

                                          if (error!=nil)
                                          {
                                              completionBlock(nil,error,responseStatusCode);
                                              [task suspend];
                                          }
                                          else
                                          {
                                              NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
                                              completionBlock(dic,error,responseStatusCode);
                                              [task suspend];
                                          }
                                      }];
        [task resume];

}
```

Then you can use that class for whole App and you don't need to create custom `Delegates` always.

Then Use that where you want Like :

```
NSURLRequest *request;
    /*
     Configure your Request Here
     */

[APIHelperClass apiCallSharedSessionPOST:request withCompletionHandlar:^(NSDictionary *dicResult, NSError *error, int status) {

}];
```

Comment: Hi Piyush Patel, Thanks for help but I still need delegate to return my value outside framework. 

I got issued that whenever I done with NSURLSessionDataTask, delegate is became null, I think it cause that delegate already released after I got response from NSURLSessionDataTask, So I tried to change @property delegate to strong and it work.

I can return my value using delegate again.

Thanks